# Will a bad network card affect a USB network adaptor?

Tags: networking, network-adapter, wireless-adapter

If my network card that is integrated into the motherboard stops working, will this have an effect on a USB wireless network adaptor I plug in? 
If so, will inserting a new network card fix this?

Thank you.

Max

Answer (score 1):

No, and its entirely possible, and common to have multiple network adapters working at once, or to select one over the other. Laptops commonly do this(with mini pci-e cards for wifi and onboard ethernet), as do quite a few modern PCs that come with internal wifi cards (which are often internally USB based).

I'd warn though, that its PRETTY rare for onboard ethernet adaptors to fail, so I'd take a good hard look at my motherboard. Anything that could knock out the ethernet chip could knock out other things as well

Answer (score 0):

Physical Network Cards are independant from one another. If one is broken, the others will continue to work.

Answer (score 0):

No, your network card is separated from your USB hub and therefore your USB devices. The only case which I'd answer this question with a yes is if there were some sort of electrical spark or other damage caused by the device, but something like that happening would be extremely rare.

If the network card simply stopped working, you should have no problems using a USB WiFi dongle. Just make sure you install the drivers first :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously if a "network card" is bad and you insert a new network card in its place, then that's going to fix it isn't it.  Though since your network interface is not on a card(it's integrated as you say), so inserting a new card won't fix that one but it will work around the problem by giving you a new way to connect, and makes having one bad network interface into a non-issue. And not only will a USB network adaptor or any network adaptor, not be affected by some other network interface being bad, it is actually a good workaround to the problem. Just as inserting a new card would be a good workaround to the problem